# Supose $f'(x) \ge M \gt 0$ for every $x \in [0,1]$...

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives

Supose $f'(x)\ge M\gt 0$ for every  $x \in [0,1]$. Prove that there exists an interval of length $\frac 14$ where $$| f(x) |\ge \frac M4$$

Comment: If I use the mean value theorem on $[x,x+\frac 14]$  I get $$f(x+\frac 14) - f(x) \ge \frac M4$$. But I don't know where to go from here...

Comment: Take cases depending on the value of $f(0)$. It might help to draw a picture.

Comment: Supose $f(0)\ge0$. Using the Mean Value Theorem on $[0,\frac14]$ we get (for some $c_1$):
$$M\le f'(c_1)=\frac{f(\frac14)-f(0)}{\frac14}
\Rightarrow f(\frac14)\ge \frac M4+f(0) \ge \frac M4$$
Therefore, any $x$ greater than $\frac14$ will satisfy that $|f(x)|\ge\frac M4$ so take $I=[\frac 14,\frac 34].$ What if $f(0)<0$??

Comment: First answer what if $f(1)<0$. Then also consider the case when $f(x_0)=0$ for some $x_0$. Consider the case $x_0\le\frac12$ which is done similarly to what you did. Then consider the case $x_0\ge\frac12$ which will be done similar to the case $f(1)\le0$ (see answer for more details).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint.

If $f(x_0)\ge 0$ for some $x_0\in[0,\frac12]$ then $f(x)\ge \frac M4$ for all $x\in[x_0+\frac14,x_0+\frac12]\subset[0,1]$.

If $f(x_0)\le 0$ for some $x_0\in[\frac12,1]$ then $f(x)\le -\frac M4$ for all $x\in[x_0-\frac12,x_0-\frac14]\subset[0,1]$.

There are no other cases to consider.

Let me list the cases in a different way, trying to match your approach in the comments.

Case (A). $f(x)>0$ for all $x$. In particular $f(0)>0$. You have done this case in a comment (with $f(0)\ge0$).

Case (B). $f(x)<0$ for all $x$. In particular $f(1)<0$. Similarly to what you did, $f(x)\le-\frac M4$ on $[\frac12,\frac34]$ (notice you only need an interval of length $\frac14$, not $\frac12$ even though you found one of length $\frac12$ in the comments).

Case (C). $f(x_0)=0$ for some $x_0$. If $x_0\le\frac12$ consider the interval $[x_0+\frac14,x_0+\frac12]$ where $f(x)\ge\frac M4$. If $x_0\ge\frac12$ consider the interval $[x_0-\frac12,x_0-\frac14]$ where $f(x)\le-\frac M4$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose without loss of generality (why?) that $f(x) < 0$ or $f(x) > 0$ for all $x \in [z, z + \frac{1}{4}] \subset [0,1]$. Then, we have

$|f(z)| = |f(z)- f(z + \frac{1}{4})| + |f(z + \frac{1}{4})| \geq \frac{M}{4}$. (By the mean value theorem).

Therefore, $|f(z)| \geq \frac{M}{4}$. Since $|f'(x)| = f'_{+}(x) - f'_{-}(x)$. We have,

$|f(x)| \geq \frac{M}{4}, \forall x \in [z, z + \frac{1}{4}]$
Or
$|f(x)| \geq \frac{M}{4}, \forall x \in [z - \frac{1}{4}, z]$.